# Is there a maximum dialogHeight and dialogWidth for a showModalDialog in IE8?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to size a webpage dialog box but no matter what I change the height/width to, the size doesn't change.

window.showModalDialog ('c1270.srf?c1270-s11',
   'dialogWidth=800px;dialogHeight=400px');

Comment: do you mean an alert?

Comment: No, not an alert.  window.showModalDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options` for [`showModalDialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog) are "CSS" type:

```
window.showModalDialog ('c1270.srf?c1270-s11', '', 'dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:400px');
```

Notice also empty `argument` argument.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked, I think it was the empty argument because I have others that are working with an '=' instead of the CSS ':' but they also don't have the empty argument.  To be consistent and compliant I'll change the others to "CSS" type.  Either way it worked.  Thank you for the help and quick response.